# python/scapy DNS sniffer and parser

Tags: python, dns, scapy, sniffer

I have python/scapy sniffer for DNS. I am able to sniff DNS messages and get IP/UDP source and destination IP address and ports but I have problems parsing DNS part
I would appreciate some help or solution to work this out.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *
from datetime import datetime
import time
import datetime
import sys

############# MODIFY THIS PART IF NECESSARY ###############
interface = 'eth0'
filter_bpf = 'udp and port 53'

# ------ SELECT/FILTER MSGS
def select_DNS(pkt):
    pkt_time = pkt.sprintf('%sent.time%')
# ------ SELECT/FILTER DNS MSGS
    try:
        if DNSQR in pkt and pkt.dport == 53:
        # queries
           print '[**] Detected DNS QR Message at: ' + pkt_time
           # 
        elif DNSRR in pkt and pkt.sport == 53:
        # responses
           print '[**] Detected DNS RR Message at: ' + pkt_time
 # 
    except:
        pass
# ------ START SNIFFER 
sniff(iface=interface, filter=filter_bpf, store=0,  prn=select_DNS)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> ls(DNS)
id         : ShortField           = (0)
qr         : BitField             = (0)
opcode     : BitEnumField         = (0)
aa         : BitField             = (0)
tc         : BitField             = (0)
rd         : BitField             = (0)
ra         : BitField             = (0)
z          : BitField             = (0)
rcode      : BitEnumField         = (0)
qdcount    : DNSRRCountField      = (None)
ancount    : DNSRRCountField      = (None)
nscount    : DNSRRCountField      = (None)
arcount    : DNSRRCountField      = (None)
qd         : DNSQRField           = (None)
an         : DNSRRField           = (None)
ns         : DNSRRField           = (None)
ar         : DNSRRField           = (None)
>>> ls(DNSQR)
qname      : DNSStrField          = ('.')
qtype      : ShortEnumField       = (1)
qclass     : ShortEnumField       = (1)
>>> ls(DNSRR)
rrname     : DNSStrField          = ('.')
type       : ShortEnumField       = (1)
rclass     : ShortEnumField       = (1)
ttl        : IntField             = (0)
rdlen      : RDLenField           = (None)
rdata      : RDataField           = ('')
>>>
```

If the above layer definitions and fields are not enough, you can either [define your own layer](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/build_dissect.html) and decode the packet using your custom layer, or simply retrieve the data straight from the raw payload. As for the timestamp, you can do pkt.time.

Comment: thx but i have problems with additional answers and additional records. I am not able to get them

Comment: @user1627588 Ugh, by editing your original question, my answer now seems almost completely irrelevant. Please don't do this in the future. The question of not being able to retrieve fields, and not being able to retrieve fields under certain specific questions are two completely different questions.

Comment: sorry man. You are completely right. Your answer does not seems relevant after editing. I did not think this way. I did not think at all. Should i somehow change it back?

Comment: @user1627588 If you can, I think it would be best to change the question back to what it was actually asking before, and you can simply submit a new question with your more specific version. Hopefully your new question will get some answers. Cheers.

Comment: i did it and changed the question back. sorry once again

Comment: @user1627588 Hey, no problem, I am not even sure whether my answer really deserves to be accepted as an answer. In my answer I was just trying to point out the obvious stuff in case you have missed anything. Again, cheers.

Comment: yeap. you did help me as well as some nice people out there. i just started learning python as pastime 4 months ago and any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I landed here while *Googling* `scapy parse DNS queries` (in my case i'm dealing with a captured pcap file)

**this is my solution:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.dns import DNSRR, DNS, DNSQR

pcap = '/path/.../to/.../pcap/.../.pcap'
pkts = rdpcap(pcap)

for p in pkts:
    if p.haslayer(DNS):   
        if p.qdcount > 0 and isinstance(p.qd, DNSQR):
            name = p.qd.qname
        elif p.ancount > 0 and isinstance(p.an, DNSRR):
            name = p.an.rdata
        else:
            continue

        print name
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tool recently, I think you mean something like this
#!/usr/bin/env python

```
from scapy.all import *
from datetime import datetime
import time

interface = 'eth0'
filter_bpf = 'udp and port 53'

def process_dns(pkt):
    if DNSQR in pkt and pkt.dport == 53:
        print('[**] Detected DNS Query at: ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        print('Source IP: ' + pkt[IP].src)
        print('Destination IP: ' + pkt[IP].dst)
        print('Source Port: ' + str(pkt[UDP].sport))
        print('Destination Port: ' + str(pkt[UDP].dport))
        print('Query Name: ' + pkt[DNSQR].qname.decode('utf-8'))
        print('Query Type: ' + str(pkt[DNSQR].qtype))
    elif DNSRR in pkt and pkt.sport == 53:
        print('[**] Detected DNS Response at: ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        print('Source IP: ' + pkt[IP].src)
        print('Destination IP: ' + pkt[IP].dst)
        print('Source Port: ' + str(pkt[UDP].sport))
        print('Destination Port: ' + str(pkt[UDP].dport))
        print('Response Name: ' + pkt[DNSRR].rrname.decode('utf-8'))
        print('Response Type: ' + str(pkt[DNSRR].type))

sniff(iface=interface, filter=filter_bpf, store=0, prn=process_dns)
```